# How to handle blur event to implement custom logic in Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

I am new to react/next js and formik & Yup. I want call some database api on blur of input field which will bring some data, check database level validation and bring data for next input field accordingly. but its not working. on changing of onblur event of input field is not invoking the functionality of validation. its just invoking the handleAcNameExists() function. I used  handleBlur('accName'); to call for validation purpose but not working.

here is my code.

```
import CustomerDTO from "@/types/CustomerDTO";
import CustomerService from "@/service/CustomerService";
import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { CustomerSchema } from "@/schemas";

type AnotherComponentProps = {
    onToggle: () => void;
  };

const Edit = ({onToggle}:AnotherComponentProps) => {
    const [customerData, setCustomerData] = useState<CustomerDTO>({
        accId:0,
        accName: '',
        address: '',
        gstNo: '',
        mobNo: '',
        oppBal: '',
        balType: '',
        eId: '',
        panNo: '',
        creditLimit: ''
      });
    
      const { values, errors, touched, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit } =
    useFormik({
      initialValues : customerData,
      validationSchema: CustomerSchema,
      onSubmit: async (values, action) => {
        console.log(
            "values ",
            values
          );
          console.log(
            " customerData ",
            customerData
          );
       
        const status = await CustomerService.saveCustomer(values)
        console.log('status '+status);
           if(status === true)
           {
            toast.success('Customer Saved.!');
           }
        action.resetForm();
      },
    });

    const handleAcNameExists = () => {
     // Api call and other logic
     console.log('in handleAcNameExists');
        handleBlur('accName');   
    
      };
      
  return (
    <div>
    <h3>Edit Customers </h3>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="accName" className="form-label">Customer Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="accName"
            name="accName"
            className="form-control"
            value={values.accName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleAcNameExists}
            autoFocus
          />
           {touched.accName && errors.accName && (
            <div className="error">{errors.accName}</div>
            )}
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="address" className="form-label">Customer Address:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="address"
            name="address"
            value={values.address}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className="form-control"
          />
          {touched.address && errors.address && (
            <div className="error">{errors.address}</div>
            )}
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="gstNo" className="form-label">GST No:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="gstNo"
            name="gstNo"
            value={values.gstNo}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="mobNo" className="form-label">Mobile Number:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="mobNo"
            name="mobNo"
            value={values.mobNo}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="oppBal" className="form-label">Opening Balance:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="oppBal"
            name="oppBal"
            value={values.oppBal}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="balType" className="form-label">Balance Type:</label>
          <select
            id="balType"
            name="balType"
            value={values.balType}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className="form-select"
          >
            <option value="Dr">Debit</option>
            <option value="Cr">Credit</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="creditLimit" className="form-label">Credit Limit:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="creditLimit"
            name="creditLimit"
            value={values.creditLimit}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-6">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={onToggle} >
          Show
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Edit
```

)
}

export default Edit

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe you intend to do some logic on `blur` event. Well you can do that by passing your desired function to the `onBlur` prop. But you should note that now you have to set the 'touched-ness' of the input manually (if that's even a word).
That is done by calling the Formik's `setFieldTouched` function. Find out about the syntax [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#formik-render-methods-and-props).
I suppose you are that new to Formik that you don't know about fields being touched. That state determines if the error message should be shown or not. I think this is the problem you are having. Your fields are not being touched properly. Also you can find more about that [here](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#visited-fields) and [here](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation).